# cordova + angularjs + nodejs(Express) $http json always get 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova, express

I am using cordova + angularjs + nodejs(Express) to test in android environment. Now I am trying to get some data by $http(), but I always get 404 error (by the alert below).

Client Code ( AngularJs )

```
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : "http://192.168.1.4:8888/login",
            data    : ""
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success");
            alert(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            alert("error");// <== always gets here
            alert(status); // <== 404
        }).
        finally(function() {
          alert("finally");
        });
```

Server Code (NodeJs+Express)

```
...
app.get('/login',function(req, res){ 
    res.set({'Content-Type':'application/json','Encodeing':'utf8'});  
    res.json({name:"jj"}); 
}) ;
app.listen(8888);
```

I can get the json string by visit http://192.168.1.4:8888/login by Chrome,
[image: visit server by browser, return 200]

I searched a lot of stuff but still can't solve my problem, could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http method is post, it needs to be get.

Comment: Just a another question, if I need use 'POST' method to submit some data, is there a way that angularJS handle the response other than 404?

Comment: It only gave a 404 response because you tried to post against a url that only allows gets.  When the url allows post it will return whatever you specify to return.